# ionic 3 pass data in api

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

i am using api in api their is a parameter of cardnumber . I am inserting data in url but its now working .

api is http://api.igiinsurance.com.pk:8888/insurance_IGItakaful/insurance-api/get_company_employee.php?company_id=1053&offset=0&limit=10&health_card=here the card number come

i am inserting like this

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public httpClient: HttpClient, 
 public navParams: NavParams) {

    this.userData = this.navParams.get('x');
    console.log(this.userData.Cardnumber);


 this.clientData = this.httpClient.get('http://url.come.here/get_company_employee.php?company_id=1053&offset=0&limit=10&health_card="this.userData.Cardnumber');

 this.clientData.subscribe(udata => {
  console.log('my data: ', udata);
})
```

Comment: you aren´t calling any insert method of your API. You need something like updateClientData. send the params to the method and subscribe with it. Take a look at this article https://medium.com/@chathurangijks/create-rest-api-with-json-server-and-consume-in-angular-5-httpclient-using-ionic-3-application-66bee52deb6e

Answer (score -1):

This is how i send parameters. Solved

```
 this.clientData = this.httpClient.get(url',
   {
     params: {
     health_card: this.userData
     },
  });
```